# I am trying to solve an assignment on coursera..its called best hospital

Tags: r

I was trying to solve an assignment on courser....It is to find the best hospital in USA.
I made a small dataset on the basis of the original dataset..
when I the function on small dataset it gives correct answer. but when I run the function on bigger dataset, for some values I am getting result but for other I am getting the following error:

[1] 
Levels: 
Warning message:
In best("TX", "heart attack") : NAs introduced by coercion

Here is my code:

```
 ##THE best hospital problem
    best <- function(state, outcome) {
      setwd("C:/Users/Praveen/Documents/R/COURSERA/R-programming/Week 3/Programming_Assignment")

###Reading the dataset
      x <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv" , header =TRUE)
##vector of unique states in the data set
      statevector <- unique(x$State)
## vector of outcomes
      outcomevector <- c("heart attack" , "heart failure" , "pneumonia")
## checking validity of arguments      
      if(!(state %in% statevector)){
        stop("Invalid State")
      } else if(!(outcome %in% outcomevector)){
        stop("Invalid Outcome")
      } else {
        message("OK")  }
## Sub setting the data and getting relevant data set 
      X <- subset(x, x$State== state)
## if outcome is "heart attack", then calculate minimum value in 11th column in ##the data subset; Again sub setting  the data on the basis of minimum value in ##11th column      
      if(outcome == outcomevector[1]){
      y <- as.numeric(as.character(X[,11]))
      z <- min(y, na.rm=TRUE)
      z
    subsetx <- subset(X, X[,11]==z)
    answer <- subsetx[2]
    answer
## if outcome is "heart failure", then calculate minimum value in 17th column ##in the data subset; Again sub setting  the data on the basis of minimum value ##in 17th column 
    } else if (outcome == outcomevector[2]){
      y <- as.numeric(as.character(X[,17]))
      z <- min(y, na.rm=TRUE)
      z
      subsetx <- subset(X, X[,17]==z)
      answer <- subsetx[2]
      answer
## if outcome is "heart attack", then calculate minimum value in 23rd column in ##the data subset; Again sub setting  the data on the basis of minimum value in ##23rd column 
    } else {
      y <- as.numeric(as.character(X[,23]))
      z <- min(y, na.rm=TRUE)
      z
      subsetx <- subset(X, X[,23]==z)
      answer <- subsetx[2]
      answer}
##if there are two or more equal minimum values, then sort alphabetically and ##select the hospital which comes first alphabetivcally
      FA <- answer[with(answer, order(Hospital.Name)), ]
      FFA <- FA[1]
      FFANS <- droplevels(FFA)
      FFANS
    }
```

Comment: It's not an error, only a warning.

Comment: You should try and narrow the problem down. Figure out which line causes the error and then find out what data causes this line to break. Then you most likely have found the underlying problem. If you cannot solve the problem, then it is worth posting. But you should try to narrow it down first.

Comment: This is also incorrect in several ways. `subset(x, x$State== state)`. Read he help page for `?subset` more carefully ... and then don't use it inside functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the code, but the direct problem is that you are being bitten by the factor bug. Compare these values:

```
class(z)
#[1] "numeric"

class(X[,11])
#[1] "factor"
```

So when you run this command, `subsetx <- subset(X, X[,11]==z)`, you will not get a match even though one exists. Try this instead:

```
subset(X, as.numeric(X[,11])==z)
```

The vector was wrapped in the function `as.numeric` to give this output.

```
best("TX", "heart attack")
#OK
#[1] CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER
#Levels: CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER
#Warning message:
#In best("TX", "heart attack") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

You will still get a warning because you did not eliminate factors from the beginning. It's difficult to tell where to start fixing the approach, but it may get you through the assignment.

**Update**

You can start on the right foot by adding two arguments to `read.csv`, we will set `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` so strings remain as characters. And `na.strings` to `Not Available`. This tells R what to look for in the file to determine missing values.

```
x <- read.csv(file , header =TRUE, stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings="Not Available")
```

With this corrective step added, you can now take out all of the `as.numeric` and `as.character` parts. Look what I did with the heart attack section:

```
if("heart attack" == outcomevector[1]){
      y <- X[,11]
      z <- min(y, na.rm=TRUE)

    subsetx <- subset(X, X[,11] %in% z)
    answer <- subsetx[2]
    answer
```

Now `y` can just take the value of `X[,11]` directly. And `subsetx` doesn't need any special treatment either.

Towards the bottom, you can now take out the last lines that drop the factor levels. I changed the ending to:

```
FA <- answer[with(answer, order(Hospital.Name)), ]
FA[1]
```

Now when the code is run it works without warnings:

```
best("TX", "heart attack")
#OK
#[1] "CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER"
```

**Update 2**

Here is a shortened code that will work:

```
best2 <- function(state, outcome) {
      setwd("C:/Users/Praveen/Documents/R/COURSERA/R-programming/Week 3/Programming_Assignment")    
      x <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv" , header =TRUE, stringsAsFactors=F)          
      outcomevector <- c("heart attack" , "heart failure" , "pneumonia")         
      if(!(state %in% unique(x$State))) stop("Invalid State")
      if(!(outcome %in% outcomevector)) stop("Invalid Outcome")

      X <- x[x$State== state,]
      names(X)[c(11, 17, 23)] <- outcomevector
      answer <- X[X[,outcome] == min(X[,outcome]), ][2]    
      FA <- answer[with(answer, order(Hospital.Name)), ]
      FA[1]   
    }
```

Comment: I am new to R programming.....and learning through courser and other resources....Can someone suggest me how to learn R.....I am confused... I tried to learn from coursera. But they start with basics abd suddenly switch to programming assignments....How should I learn R

Comment: I learned with the same Coursera class. I did not know R at all last year.

Comment: Can you tell me what to do in case I am stuck with my code....like it is pointed out that there are many mistakes in my code....but when I was working with smaller data set I found no errors...How can I know whether my code is having any mistake or not.  Had I not worked on the bigger dataset or if I had started with the bigger dataset then how could I have known whats wrong with my code

Comment: I went through your function line by line. I noticed the problem that way. It's hard but when you get through it, R is a very rewarding language to learn. I encourage you to keep trying. And keep asking questions.

Comment: Thank you very much.......I have been trying to learn for last 2 months and I feel like I am learning very slowly.... I really appreciate you...Thanks once again

Comment: In this code you wrote "stringsAsFactors=F". Is it same as colClasses= "character" ?

Comment: No because `colClasses = 'character'` will make everything in the data a character. `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` will only tell R to keep everything that is a character string to stay a character string.

Comment: I just added a new version of the code that I think is shorter and faster. Study that example.

Comment: what I was doing in 3 "if statements", it is doing in a single step... Beautiful code.... Now I am feeling the strength of R.... nice code..

Comment: thanks, like the part where you update the outcome back into the data frame so that we can select directly off of it using the outcome values.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you take care of the `Not Available` entries (Your assignment asks you to do so)

First convert all the `Not Available` to `NA`:

This is done by simply adding the `na.strings = "Not Available"` to the read statement

`x <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv" , header =TRUE, na.strings = "Not Available")`

Then take them out, either by using complete.cases or by `na.omit`

`completedata <- (na.omit(x))`

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this question but figured it out in the end. Here is my solution with comments on why I used certain pieces of code. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this as I'm a beginner in R especially when I'm saving down a few dataframe variables, so feel free to enhance my code if you see any opportunities to do so:

```
best <- function(state, outcome) {
  ## Read outcome data
  outcome_read <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
  ## subset out only the columns you need.
  subsetOutcome <- outcome_read[, c(7, 11, 17, 23, 2)]
  # convert to numerics as some of the items within the columns were read in as chars. 
  # you can see it if you run str(outcome_read)
  subsetOutcome$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure <- as.numeric(subsetOutcome$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure)
  subsetOutcome$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia <- as.numeric(subsetOutcome$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia)
  subsetOutcome$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack <- as.numeric(subsetOutcome$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack)
  ## Check that state is valid by using the is.element function. It will check whether the element exist within your column.
  if (!is.element(state, subsetOutcome[,1])) {
    stop("invalid state")
  }
  # checking whether the outcome agrument is a valid health condition.
  condition <- factor(c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia"))
  if (!any(c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia") == outcome)) {
    stop("invalid outcome")
  } 
  # I determine the col number here by determining the level of the condition factor. For eg, if the outcome was
  # heart failure, the level will be 2. This will be the col number.
  colNumber <- as.numeric(condition[levels(condition) == outcome])
  # self check - printing to see if the col number make sense.
  print(colNumber)
  ## removing all the NAs within the outcome column (eg, heart failure column) you are looking at.
  resultState <- subsetOutcome[complete.cases(subsetOutcome[,colNumber+1]),]
  # subsetting your dataframe to only include the state you are looking at.
  resultState <- subset(resultState, resultState$State == state)
  # order your results based on the condition (eg, heart failure), then the hospital name.
  result <- resultState[order(resultState[,colNumber+1], resultState[,5]), ]
  # returning the first row and just the hospital.name column
  result[1,"Hospital.Name"]
}
```